# Why are automotive connectors and wires so big?

Tags: connector, automotive

Cars and motorcycles have many electronic sensors which are small. But it seems they are all connected with big connectors and at least 22AWG wires. Why?

I would think 30AWG wires and tiny connectors should do the job because there is very little current going through those wires.

Or is the idea that car and bike mechanics maybe wear gloves and work with lots of force so the developers makes the wires and connectors big so nothing gets easily destroyed?

Any idea? There must be a logical reason for this.

Comment: They also have many devices and bulbs etc that need greater currents... Many cars have a variety of wire sizes in use based on the current demand...

Comment: To survive the activities of mechanics and body-shop people.

Answer (score 6):

High heat, weather and vibration environment. Lower gauge, high strand count wire is used to reduce resistance, increase physical strength and longevity. Large connectors are used to ensure they stay together and these connectors are often waterproof and high heat tolerances. The cable insulator and connector plastic is oil, gas and other automotive fluid resistant as well.

If multibillion dollar companies thought they could shave pennies off every cable and connector by using smaller ones, they would.